# pxe boot, IPV6 delays installer 15 minutes

Tags: pxe, preseed, debian-installer

Using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Looking through the log I can see the below error is shown 6 times.

```
##IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
```

With around 3 minutes apart each other

```
Dec  7 04:18:42 net-retriever: gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key "
Dec  7 04:20:50 kernel: [  181.269458] IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
Dec  7 04:23:20 kernel: [  331.462975] IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
Dec  7 04:26:34 kernel: [  525.079430] IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
Dec  7 04:29:13 kernel: [  683.283766] IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
Dec  7 04:32:15 kernel: [  865.676251] IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
Dec  7 04:35:35 kernel: [ 1064.907229] IPv6 addrconf: prefix with wrong length 48
Dec  7 04:36:39 anna[4606]: DEBUG: resolver (ext2-modules): package doesn't exist (ignored)
Dec  7 04:36:39 anna[4606]: DEBUG: resolver (ext3-modules): package doesn't exist (ignored)
```

The network section of my preseed looks as follows:

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select eth0    
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean true    
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string x.x.200.100    
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.0    
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4    
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string x.x.200.1    
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true    
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string server.company.com    
d-i netcfg/get_domain string company.com
```